# How can I prove this inequality for a harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I need a hand with this problem. I have to prove that for a particle in any quantum state in an harmonic potential

$$  \langle X\rangle    \leq2\Delta E\Delta P/(m  \omega^2  \hslash)
$$

Here's my idea:

We know that for a harmonic oscillator

$$ E=p^2/(2m)+m\omega^2x^2/2
$$

Now partially differentiating to get uncertainties we obtain

$$ \Delta E = p\Delta p/m+m\omega^2x\Delta x 
$$
if we multiply both sides by $\Delta p$ we get

$$ \Delta E\Delta p=p(\Delta p)^2/m+m\omega^2x\Delta x\Delta p
$$

Now using Heisenberg's uncertainty principle,

$$ \Delta E\Delta p\geq p(\Delta p)^2/m+m\omega^2x  \hslash/2
$$

At this point I don't know how to carry on. Any hints?

Thanks for your help in advance and I hope you could understand my English.

Comment: But I understand that this is a quantum oscillator. In that case p is an operator, -iħ ∂/∂x .

Comment: Also, which observable is X ? Is it position? The average position is zero. You can easily see this, in Wikipedia you can find the eigenfunctions of the quantum harmonic oscillator. About Δp you can calculate it using the same eigenfunctions, and ΔE seems to me that is ħω.

Comment: you are right Sofia, X is the position operator, but its average value can be non-zero as the particle can be in any quantum state, not only in a quatum state with a particular eigenfunction, but also a linear sum of eigenfunctions. I think I might be wrong because I'm using concepts from classical mechanics instead of those from quantum mechanics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already realized, you are messing up classical and quantum concepts. The [uncertainty principle for two general observables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson.E2.80.93Schr.C3.B6dinger_uncertainty_relations) for a particular quantum state is given by
$$\Delta A\Delta B\geq\frac{1}{2}\left|\langle [A,B]\rangle\right|,$$
where $\Delta$ is the standard deviation and $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is the expected value of an observable for the given state. In this case, using $A=H$, the hamiltonian, and $B=P$, the momentum, we can check that for the harmonic oscilator
\begin{align}[H,P]&=[\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2+\frac{1}{2m}P^2,P]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2[X^2,P]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\left(X[X,P]+[X,P]X\right)\\
&=i\hbar m\omega^2X\end{align}
Substituting the above relation on the inequality, gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Mateus for your help. I was heading in the wrong direction. After all it wasn't as difficult as I thought. Now I know I have to be more careful when using some expressions.